# How do I code walk in elisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm trying to open a file and read through the sexps. If the form has setq in its first position then traverse the rest of the form adding the in the setq form to an alist.

```
;;; File passwords.el.gpg
(setq twitter-password "Secret"
      github-password "Sauce")
```

My goal is to able to construct an alist from the pairs in the setq forms in teh file. How I even start?

Comment: First, learn you some grammar. Sorry for trolling, but I understood nothing.

Comment: I think it would be way easier to have an alist in passwords.el and `setq` based on the alist's value.

Comment: -1: I cannot understand what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I second the recommendation that you store the passwords in an actual alist and, if necessary, set whatever variables you need to based on that.

That aside, here's another solution that tries to break things out a bit. The `-partition` function is from the [dash.el](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el) library, which I highly recommend.

You don't really need to "walk" the code, just `read` it in and check if its `car` is `setq`. The remainder of the form should then be alternating symbols and strings, so you simply partition them by 2 and you have your alist. (Note that the "pairs" will be proper lists as opposed to the dotted pairs in Sean's solution).

```
(defun setq-form-p (form)
  (eq (car form) 'setq))

(defun read-file (filename)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert-file-literally filename)
    (read (buffer-substring-no-properties 1 (point-max)))))

(defun credential-pairs (form)
  (-partition 2 (cdr form)))

(defun read-credentials-alist (filename)
  (let ((form (read-file filename)))
    (credential-pairs form)))

;; usage:
(read-credentials-alist "passwords.el")
```

Alternatively, here's how it would work if you already had the passwords in an alist, like so

```
(defvar *passwords*
  '((twitter-password "Secret")
    (github-password "Sauce")))
```

And then wanted to set the variable `twitter-password` to `"Sauce"` and so on. You would just map over it:

```
(mapcar #'(lambda (pair)
            (let ((name (car pair))
                  (value (cadr pair)))
              (set name value)))
        *passwords*)
```

Comment: Yeah, I was worrying about something that just read would solve. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use streams to read in the files (read-from-string) and then do the usual elisp hacking.  The below isn't robust, but you get the idea.  On a file, pwd.el that has your file, it returns the alist ((github-password . "Sauce") (twitter-password . "Secret"))

```
(defun readit (file)
  "Read file.  If it has the form (sexp [VAR VALUE]+), return
an alist of the form ((VAR . VALUE) ...)"
  (let* (alist
         (sexp-len
          (with-temp-buffer 
            (insert-file-contents file)
            (read-from-string (buffer-substring 1 (buffer-size)))))
         (sexp (car sexp-len)))
    (when (equal (car sexp) 'setq)
      (setq sexp (cdr sexp))
      (while sexp
        (let* ((l (car sexp))
               (r (cadr sexp)))
          (setq alist (cons (cons l r) alist)
                sexp (cddr sexp)))))
    alist))

(readit "pwd.el")
```